# The Title of Document Runs off the page, as part of header on page 3

Tags: header-footer, line-breaking

Here's my preamble:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{geometry}                % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options. There are lots.
\geometry{letterpaper}                   % ... or a4paper or a5paper or ... 
%\geometry{landscape}                % Activate for for rotated page geometry
%\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}    % Activate to begin paragraphs with an empty line rather than an indent
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\DeclareGraphicsRule{.tif}{png}{.png}{`convert #1 `dirname #1`/`basename #1 .tif`.png}

\title{\emph{Research Proposal:}\\Perceptual Effects of Cross-Contextualized Soundscapes within the Built Environment}
```

Here's what happens:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "Any ideas?" Do you want an abbreviated header or perhaps a line-break in the header?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You probably want to use `\title[Short version]{Long version}`; if you really need that the header shows the whole title, something more has to be done. A tip: if you highlight your code and press the `{}` button, it will appear as I did in my edit.

Answer (score 6):

In the `amsart` document class, you can provide a "short title", to be used in the running heads, as an option to the `\title` command. For instance, you could type

```
\title[Perceptual Effects of Cross-Contextualized Soundscapes]{\emph{Research 
 Proposal:}\\Perceptual Effects of Cross-Contextualized Soundscapes within the 
 Built Environment}}
```

and now you'll get "Perceptual Effects of Cross-Contextualized Soundscapes" as the short or running title.