# Removing or Editing the header on each page in LyX

Tags: lyx, titles, amsart

My document is in (AMS article) mode. The title of my paper shows up as a header on each page. The problem is that the title is too long and it overlaps with the page number. I would like to use a different (shorter) header (one header for all the pages except the title page) or erase the header on each page altogether. How would I do either of these?

[image]

If the source code or preamble needs to be edited, can you explain how I can go about making the edit in LyX? (I.e., do I use ERT, edit the settings or something else?)

Here's the source code for the title, but I am not sure if it's helpful:

```
 \title{{\small{EST}}}

 \maketitle
```

My preamble is empty.

Edit: How can I make any of the suggested edits in the linked question in LyX?

Comment: the optional argument to `\title` is what you should be using: `\title[short version]{long version}`.  in all document classes i'm familiar with, any heading that can be placed in a running head provides this option.  see [The Title of Document Runs off the page, as part of header on page 3](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38089/579).

Comment: @barbarabeeton  Part of my question was on how to enter this info into LyX. Can you suggest how to make any of these edits into the LyX document? Am I allowed to directly change the source code in LyX? If so, how can I do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insert the title using the `Title` paragraph style. Then, while still within the title (preferably at the front, although it doesn't matter), Insert > Short Title or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd> and type the title that will be displayed in the header for all pages that are not the title page:

[image]

Your output should resemble

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to have the header alternate between two short titles?

Comment: @TheSubstitute: Between an odd/even page? You'll have to use an ERT like `\oddevenpage` and include [the command definition](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ozV4V.png) in your Document > Settings... > LaTeX Preamble.

Comment: Yes, between odd/even pages. I inserted the ERT and updated the preamble. I am able to get a PDF but the margins do not alternate. Instead the title is the same as the title of the paper (or if I apply your original answer they show the short title instead). Is the ERT supposed to be inserted within a particular part of the document?

Comment: @TheSubstitute: You need to place `\oddevenhead` in an ERT in the header. Note though that the AMS article class issues a `oneside` document class option. If you want an alternating left/right page setup, you need to add `twoside` as Custom Class option.